# How to find an approximation of power series to correct to within $10^{-7}$ as faster?

Tags: integration, power-series, approximation

If I approximate a $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{0.5} \frac{1}{1+x^7} dx$ correct to within $10^{-7}$.

How to find it without using a calculator? Now I can't.

I usually calculate every single term, and it takes too much of time.

$$\int_{0}^{0.5} \frac{1}{1+x^7} dx = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{8*2^8} + \frac{1}{15*2^{15}} - \frac{1}{22*2^{22}} + \cdots + \frac{(-1)^n}{(7n+1)2^{7n+1}}$$

$$\int_{0}^{0.5} \frac{1}{1+x^7} dx = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{8*2^8} + \frac{1}{15*2^{15}} - \frac{1}{22*2^{22}} \approx 0.49951374$$

Comment: The error is less in absolute value than the first "neglected" term. So we can stop at the $\frac{1}{15\cdot 2^{15}}$ term.

Comment: I recognize this question from Stewart's calculus. It is truly a dumb question. In fact, due to a very restricted interval of convergence, one can not integrate beyond $1$ in your function. You cannot help it of course and your answer looks indeed correct. You may also notice that your answer is incredible close to 0.5 When you make a graph of your function you can understand why. But using series to approximate integrals becomes incredibly powerful when series are involved that have an infinite Radius of convergence. (Generally speaking, think of e-power, sine, cosine, etc)

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks for your comment. Yes. I know what is first neglected term. In order to find it, I calculate every single denominator. Any tips for me? I don't want to spend too many time to calculate this on a test.

Comment: @imranfat Yes it is! haha. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Mind you that the theory using series to approximate integrals is very important and useful. There are lots of examples where this becomes very effective. And if the series is alternating, then Andre's remark is even nicer about "cutting off" the next term as a means to estimate the error. You will probably get to those exercises as well in the near future...

Comment: @imranfat Oh. Okay! Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as you did $$\frac 1{1+x^7}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i x^{7i}$$ $$\int_{0}^{a} \frac 1{1+x^7}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i\frac {a^{7i+1}}{7i+1}$$ SInce it is alternating, for a given accuracy $\epsilon$, you need to find $n$ such that $$\frac {a^{7n+1}}{7n+1} <\epsilon$$ Treating $n$ as a continuous variable $7n+1=t$, the solution of $a^t=\epsilon t$ is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $$t=-\frac{W\left(-\frac{\log (a)}{\epsilon }\right)}{\log (a)}$$ For large values of $z$, as here, the Wikipedia page gives the approximation $$W(z)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(z)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$. In the case we are looking at $z=10^7 \log(2)$ which makes $L_1\approx15.7516$ and $L_2=2.75694$ so $t=7n+1=18.9998$ so $n=3$ should be more than sufficient. Checking the value of $t_i=\frac{a^{7i+1}}{7i+1}$ with $a=\frac 12$, we find $$t_2=\frac{1}{491520}\approx 2.03451\times 10^{-6}$$ $$t_3=\frac{1}{92274688}\approx1.08372\times 10^{-8}$$